# WordPress/Avada website not Loading in XAMPP

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, localhost

So I've been trying to get into the admin dashboard for a WordPress website that I'm supposed to be working on and for some reason my XAMPP/phpMyAdmin & Avada theme does not seem to be working properly.

When I configured XAMPP it worked fine and could reach the admin dashboard without any issues. But when I replaced the WordPress directory downloaded from the network admin and the .sql database table uploaded into phpMyAdmin I am now noticing that when I access localhost/wp/ it loads a broken page, appears to be missing the CSS (styles/images)

I've tried to navigate to locahost/wp/wp-admin/admin.php and /wp-admin/login.php and I am not able to load the files I continue to receive a "File not found" redir error.

In my own opinion it seems as though the user isn't entirely authenticated and is causing me to redir based on failed authentications OR the system is having difficulties with the folder structure to determine the areas for the "missing" wp-admin files, although I have confirmed they are physically residing within that expected location which only further confuses me.

I can upload and attach any type of document, just let me know what type of information you are looking for to assist in troubleshooting.

THANKS FOR ANY AND ALL HELP!

Answer (score 0):

## 1) Ask wp questions at [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)

2) you may have problems with `.htaccess` and `.sql` file permalinks. Ask people at the mentioned forum.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1 : Remove htaccess file from your root folder

Step 2 : check wp_option table and change site_url and home_url

Step 3 : Login into wp-admin using

http://localhost:8080/mysite/wp-admin/

Step 4 Goto setting ->paramlink and update using custom structure.

That's it.Problem solve.

Comment: What are you suggesting I change the site/home_url to?